# Electron - Error launching app

Tags: javascript, electron, iojs

I am following a tutorial on how to use Electron to make desktop apps. I have followed all of the steps but when I use `npm start` in terminal I get this error

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JoNF.png)

[Click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ojX5yz35v4M) to see the tutorial that I am following

Comment: What does your `package.json` look like?

Comment: Please post your code, not just images

Answer (score 0):

I think your node js version is outdated, so download the last version here : https://nodejs.org/en/